# How to build a windows bot (Controling UI applications on Windows)

Tags: python, node.js, automation, bots, screen-scraping

What are my options if I wanted to create a bot that opens, interacts with and terminates my windows applications?

I want to be able to read plain text, use some image recognition and interact according to pre-defined set of conditions or algorithms, something like a web scraper but for windows.

Feel free to edit my question if you know what I mean but know how to say it better XD

Comment: Python is in your tags.You can open and close programs with Python. You can also do image recognition! However, reading 'plain text' from a program is not that easy.. What actually do you want t do?

Comment: I am thinking about Python, I am actually looking at pyautogui just now, and it is going good so far. I need to read data of a stock exchange desktop app, and then check other data sources to try to have a justification for the fluctuation in a given stock, some of the data sources I use are only available on Mobile Apps, so emulators will get into the equation soon.

Comment: You checked if given source doesn't have an API? This would help a lot. If not, you can always try text recognition through OCR. Are you trying to make a stock exchange bot to make micro profit automatically?